# collision between objects and addition of onomatopoeias(splat)

Tags: perl

I have 3 objects here: 'sword', 'target' and 'splat'.
I was trying every time the sword collided with the target object, the group_death
destroy the "nib" for, the associated entity that does the actual collision
target_collision adds the splat
but none of that worked. Was following this template [git asciiquarium](https://github.com/cmatsuoka/asciiquarium/blob/master/asciiquarium). But very complex with the target object and the weapon (shark) moving.
The example I'm trying to build only the gun moves while the target is fixed.
I've tried to find other perl collision fonts, but there's nothing left.
Does anyone know and can please collaborate with some?
[2nd attempt with 28 more lines than the one below.](https://pastebin.com/5cwUbPcT) (<- script I use. I left the one below because it has less. What takes up most is just the image object).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Curses;
use Term::Animation 2.0;

my $s = Term::Animation->new();
$s->color(1); 

my @sword = (
q{
        /| _________
   O|==|* >_________>
        \|
},
q{
     /| _________
O|==|* >_________>
     \|
},
q{
        /| _________
   O|==|* >_________>
        \|
},
q{
          /| _________
     O|==|* >_________>
          \|
} );
my @launch;
push(@launch, [0,0,0,0]) for(1..10);
push(@launch, [0,0,0,1]) for(1..2);
push(@launch, [0,0,0,1]) for(1..2);
push(@launch, [0,0,0,3]) for(1..1);
$s->new_entity(
shape           => \@sword,
    position        => [0, 4, 3],
    callback_args   => [0, [@launch]],
    defeaut_color   => 'blue',
    auto_trans      => 1,
    die_offscreen   => 1,
    death_cb        => sub { group_death(@_, 'nib') },
);
my $target = q#
     ___
  ,-^   ^-.
 / _    _  \
| / \  / \ |
| \_/  \_/ |
 \   /|\  /
  |  \_/ |
   \     /
    ^---^
#;
$s->new_entity(
    type            => 'nib',
    shape           => $target,
    position        => [ 21, 1, 2],
    callback_args   => [0,0,0,0],
    die_offscreen   => 1,
    death_cb        => \&add_target,
    wrap            => 1,
    default_color   => 'Y',
    auto_trans      => 1,
    physical        => 1,
    coll_handler    => \&target_collision,
);
sub add_splat {
    my ($anim, $x, $y, $z) = @_;
    my @splat_image = (
q{



      \ | / 
      *@@@* 
    --@@@@@--
      *@@@*
      / | \



},
q{
        |
    \   |   /
     \  &  /
      &***& 
     d*@@@*b 
----&*@@@@@*&---
     q*@@@*p
      &***&
     /  &  \
    /   |   \
        |
},
q{


   *        *
      #   &
    *   @    %
@     @  @
  *  *p%  #
     @   &
       &   *
   d
});

    $s->new_entity(
        shape           => \@splat_image,
        position        => [ 19, 0, 1 ],
        default_color   => 'r',
        callback_args   => [ 0, 0, 0, .25 ],
        transparent     => ' ',
        die_frame       => 15,
    );
}
sub group_death {
        my ($entity, $s, @bound_types) = @_;
        foreach my $type (@bound_types) {
                my $bound_entities = $s->get_entities_of_type($type);
                foreach my $obj (@{$bound_entities}) {
                        $s->del_entity($obj);
                }
        }
}
sub target_collision {
        my ($target, $s) = @_;
        my $collisions = $target->collisions();
        foreach my $col_obj (@{$collisions}) {
                if($col_obj->type eq 'nib') {
                        add_splat($s, $col_obj->position());
                        $target->kill();
                        last;
                } 
        }
}
halfdelay( 2 );
for(1..500) {
    $s->animate();
    my $in = lc( getch() );
    if($in eq 'q') { last; }
}
```

Comment: I think the sword must be physical, and have the same z-coordinate as the nib for a collision to occur

Comment: Also the position of the sword stays at same (x,y,z) coordinate all the time even though its shape changes. So the sword will collide with the nib at every animation frame or at no frame at all

Comment: Btw the asciiquarium was very cool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sword must be physical, and have the same z-coordinate as the nib for a collision to occur, also the shape of the sword has multiple frames but it does not move. Then the width of the sword is calculated as the maximum width of its frames. Here is an example where the sword shape has only one frame, but that shape does move in the x-direction:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Curses;
use Term::Animation 2.0;

my $s = Term::Animation->new();
$s->color(1); 

my @sword = (
q{
     /| _________
O|==|* >_________>
     \|
}
);
my @launch;
push(@launch, [0,0,0,0]) for(1..10);
push(@launch, [1,0,0,0]) for(1..2);
push(@launch, [2,0,0,0]) for(1..2);
push(@launch, [3,0,0,0]) for(1..1);

$s->new_entity(
    type            => "sword",
    shape           => \@sword,
    position        => [0, 4, 3],
    callback_args   => [0, [@launch]],
    defeaut_color   => 'blue',
    auto_trans      => 1,
    die_offscreen   => 1,
    physical        => 1,
    coll_handler    => \&sword_collision,
);

my $target = q#
     ___
  ,-^   ^-.
 / _    _  \
| / \  / \ |
| \_/  \_/ |
 \   /|\  /
  |  \_/ |
   \     /
    ^---^
#;
$s->new_entity(
    type            => 'nib',
    shape           => $target,
    position        => [ 21, 1, 3],
    callback_args   => [0,0,0,0],
    die_offscreen   => 1,
    wrap            => 1,
    default_color   => 'Y',
    auto_trans      => 1,
    physical        => 1,
);

sub add_splat {
    my ($anim, $x, $y, $z) = @_;
    my @splat_image = (
q{



      \ | / 
      *@@@* 
    --@@@@@--
      *@@@*
      / | \



},
q{
        |
    \   |   /
     \  &  /
      &***& 
     d*@@@*b 
----&*@@@@@*&---
     q*@@@*p
      &***&
     /  &  \
    /   |   \
        |
},
q{


   *        *
      #   &
    *   @    %
@     @  @
  *  *p%  #
     @   &
       &   *
   d
});

    $s->new_entity(
        shape           => \@splat_image,
        position        => [ 19, 0, 1 ],
        default_color   => 'r',
        callback_args   => [ 0, 0, 0, .25 ],
        transparent     => ' ',
        die_frame       => 15,
    );
} # end of add_splat sub

sub sword_collision {
    my ($entity, $anim) = @_;
    my $collisions = $entity->collisions();
    if ($collisions) {
        my $type = $entity->type;
        foreach my $col_obj (@{$collisions}) {
            if($col_obj->type eq 'nib') {
                add_splat($s, $col_obj->position());
                $col_obj->kill();
                last;
            }
        }
    }
}

halfdelay( 2 );
for(1..500) {
    $s->animate();
    my $in = lc( getch() );
    if($in eq 'q') { last; }
}
```